# cannot convert type int to System.Windows.Forms.Label

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am making a random number generator but i cant get it to work. it says cannot convert type int to System.Windows.Forms.Label

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random r1 = new Random();
        string a = Text1.Text
        int b = int.Parse(a);
        b++;
        abc.Text = r1.Next(b).ToString();

    }
    }
}
```

changed it. code above is now correct. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to use [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cs4xb3d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of `abc` label;

```
abc.Text = r1.Next(b).ToString();
```

Comment: it says the value cant be null.

Comment: @user3024531 On which value exactly? Did you debug your code?

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the value to the label not the text of the label. This line

```
abc = r1.Next(b);
```

should be

```
abc.Text = r1.Next(b).ToString();
```

The error is trying to tell you that it cannot convert an `int` object into a `Label` object

Comment: when i compile it, there is no errors, but when i try to run it, it says the value cant be null and then Closes the program.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the `Random` constructor the OP uses. The problem may be that the `abc` is null.

Comment: found it. it was the string which were assigned to console.readline();

Answer (score 0):

Of course you ain't gonna assign integer to label..

You have to set the text property of the label

```
abc.Text = r1.Next(b).ToString();
```